# How to enable checkbox when hyperlink is visited

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to enable my checkbox once the hyperlink is visited, but it's not working on my end. The checkbox is still disabled despite of clicking the link. I'm hoping that you could help me with this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<asp:CheckBox ID="policyCheck" runat="server" enabled="false" />
<a target="_blank" id="Policy" href="https://google.com"> Some Policy </a>
<script>
  $('#Policy').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#Policy').is(':visited')) {
      $('#policyCheck').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#policyCheck').val('Currently enabled');
    } else {
      $('#policyCheck').val('Currently disabled');
      $('#policyCheck').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to programmatically read the value of is something visited. This is a privacy feature in browsers. Think about this;

- Is it OK if `company.com` checks if user has visited `richpeoplebank.com`?
- Is it OK if `company.com` checks if user has visited `disabledveterans.org`?
- Is it OK if `company.com` checks if user has visited
  `bad-political-party.gov`?